# Bug when use macdeployqt to create executable file for qt application

Tags: qt

When I try `macdeployqt xxx.app`to create a executable file, it will report `ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t@rpath/libc++abi.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0, reexport)"` and `ERROR: Unexpected prefix "@loader_path"`.This problem happen even if I just create a new project and try to create a executable file for it...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgoKj.png) my computer is macos10.15.4, Qt Creator 4.11.2 and Qt 5.14.2

I looked for a long time but I couldn't solve it，Is there something wrong with my operation？or is there another way to create executable file for qt application in macos?

Comment: Which Xcode version do you have installed?

Comment: Xcode version is 11.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer. For me, just switch the path to such as `/Users/yourname/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/clang_64/bin` and use `./macdeployqt xxx.app`, then the macdeplotqt can work properly. Note: only use `macdeplotqt xxx.app` it will make the error I described.